# Получение IP адреса ПК в локальной сети

Tags: delphi, ip

```
function TseaBattle.GetIP:string;
const WSVer = $101;
var wsaData: TWSAData;
    P: PHostEnt;
    Buf: array [0..127] of Char;
begin
     Result := '';
     if (WSAStartup(WSVer, wsaData) = 0) then
     begin
          if (GetHostName(@Buf, 128) = 0) then
          begin
               P := GetHostByName(@Buf);
               if (P <> nil) then
                   Result := iNet_ntoa(PInAddr(p^.h_addr_list^)^);
          end;
          WSACleanup;
     end;
end;
```

Изначально эта функция выводила верный IP адрес, но после установки VirtualBox она начала выводить IP адрес VirtualBox. Как исправить?    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете получить информацию на все имеющиеся сетевые интерфесы. [(Пример)](http://www.delphisite.ru/faq/poluchenie-ip-adresa-i-maski-dlya-vsekh-setevykh-interfeisov)

Comment: Управлять порядком возврата адресов не получится. Получить все и выбрать нужные - единственное и првильное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function LocalHostIP: string;
var HostEnt: PHostEnt;
    Buffer: array [0..63] of AnsiChar;
    GInitData: TWSAData;
begin
   Result:='';
   WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
   GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
   HostEnt:=GetHostByName(Buffer);
   if (HostEnt<>nil) then
   begin
      while (PInAddr(HostEnt^.h_addr_list^)<>nil) do
      begin
         if (Result<>'') then
            Result:=Result+';';
         Result:=Result+inet_ntoa(PInAddr(HostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^);
         Inc(HostEnt^.h_addr_list);
      end;
   end;
   WSACleanup;
end;
```